# Multiply row wise submatrices fast with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have some experimental data over time that I need to discount in the sense that each data point is weighted depending on how far back in time it lies.
For this I have the follwing code

```
import numpy as np

n_spots = 20
n_times = 5000
data = np.random.random((n_times, n_spots))

rate = 0.9
weight_vec = rate ** (n_times - 1 - np.arange(1, n_times, 1))

result = np.zeros((n_times, n_spots))

for k in range(n_times):
    result[k, :] = data[0:k, ].transpose().dot(weight_vec[n_times - 1 - k:n_times - 1])
```

The for-loop becomes very slow as `n_times` increases and I wonder if there is a way to optimize this or even eliminate the for-loop completely. There are similar cases where one can add new axes and perform the computations as a matrix product in higher dimensions but I struggle to make this work here where the sub-arrays of `data` are not equal in size.

Comment: So each `dot` uses a (nspots,k) array with a (k,) to produce a (nspots,)?  where `k` ranges from 0 to n_times.

Comment: @hpaulj exactly

Comment: I can imagine constructing a 2d `weights` array that repeats the 1d values, and setting an  upper triangle of 0s.  Then do one `dot`.  But the `cumsum` suggestions might be better. The alternatives have to tested.

Comment: I've just implemented your idea and it runs quite a bit faster than my initial solutions. However, the 2d weights matrix takes up a lot of space and blows up my memory quickly

Answer (score 0):

You're adding one extra column to current result in each step and accumulating what you've got so `np.cumsum` is a good option:

```
cols = data[:n_times-1].transpose() * weight_vec
result = np.cumsum(cols, axis=1)
result = np.insert(result.transpose(), 0, values=0, axis=0)
```

First row of `result` contains zeros so I did additional insertion. What is more, calculation of `weight_vec` could be improved itself:

```
weight_vec = np.full(n_times - 1, fill_value = 0.9)
weight_vec[0] = 1
weight_vec = np.cumprod(weight_vec)[::-1]
```

Comment: This doesn't yield the same results as my code. I'm not exactly sure why but maybe you are overlooking that each column of data is multiplied by a different weight in each iteration of the for loop?